# Boundary of a Möbius loop in the fundamental polygon

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Although [it says here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip) that, in the topology on the unit square representing the Möbius loop, the boundary consists of those points of the form $(a,a)$, I cannot find any justification as to why this must be true. Though I have attempted to prove this by proving that it is the unbounded Möbius loop that is formed by the same topology in the absence of the points of this form, this line of attack has not gotten me very far.

So, how may this be proven?

The section pertaining to which the question has been asked is quoted below:

> A torus can be constructed as the square [0,1]×[0,1] with the edges identified as (0,y)∼(1,y) (glue left to right) and (x,0)∼(x,1) (glue bottom to top). If one then also identified (x, y) ~ (y, x), then one obtains the Möbius strip. The diagonal of the square (the points (x, x) where both coordinates agree) becomes the boundary of the Möbius strip

Comment: The words "fundamental polygon" do not even occur in that link you provided.

Comment: I do apologize, but I believe I have confused my concepts. What I was referring to was the section wherein the characterization of the mobius loop as a quotient topology on a unit square was provided.

Comment: Read carefully the first sentence of [this portion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_strip#Topology) of the link you provided, it describes precisely how the Möbius band is **defined** as a quotient of a square.

Comment: So, according to this definition, how may it be proven that the set of points of the form $(a,a)$ form the boundary of the Mobius loop?

Comment: It remains quite unclear what you are asking. In the context of that definition, the set of points of the form $(a,a)$ *does not* form the boundary of the Möbius band.

Comment: A torus can be constructed as the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ with the edges identified as $(0,y) \sim (1,y)$ (glue left to right) and $(x,0) \sim (x,1)$ (glue bottom to top). If one then also identified (x, y) ~ (y, x), then one obtains the Möbius strip. The diagonal of the square (the points (x, x) where both coordinates agree) becomes the boundary of the Möbius strip.

Comment: It is in respect to this that the above question is asked.

Comment: Also, I apologize for any inconvenience I have caused as a result of my lack of clarity. Thank you for your persistence.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. What you should do is to edit your question to make that comment part of the question itself.